# How to rewrite `sin(x)^2` to cos(2*x) form in Sympy

Tags: sympy

It is easy to obtain such rewrite in other CAS like Mathematica.

```
TrigReduce[Sin[x]^2]

(*1/2 (1 - Cos[2 x])*)
```

However, in Sympy, `trigsimp` with all methods tested returns `sin(x)**2`

`trigsimp(sin(x)*sin(x),method='fu')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full "fu" method tries many different combinations of transformations to find "the best" result.

The individual transforms used in the [Fu-routines](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/fu.html) can be used to do targeted transformations. You will have to read the documentation to learn what the different functions do, but just running through the functions of the FU dictionary identifies TR8 as your workhorse here:

```
    >>> for f in FU.keys():
    ...   print("{}: {}".format(f, FU[f](sin(var('x'))**2)))
    ...
8<---
    TR8 -cos(2*x)/2 + 1/2
    TR1 sin(x)**2
8<---
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this function in previous answers to similar question. I am concerning this question, since the manualintegrate function fails to integrate many trig functions due to this kind of limitations.

Answer (score 3):

While dealing with a similar issue, reducing the order of sin(x)**6, I notice that sympy can  reduce the order of sin(x)**n with n=2,3,4,5,... by using, rewrite, expand, and then rewrite, followed by simplify, as shown here:

```
expr = sin(x)**6
expr.rewrite(sin, exp).expand().rewrite(exp, sin).simplify()
```

this returns:

```
-15*cos(2*x)/32 + 3*cos(4*x)/16 - cos(6*x)/32 + 5/16
```

That works for every power similarly to what Mathematica will do.

On the other hand if you want to reduce sin(x)**2*cos(x) a similar strategy works. In that case you have to rewrite the cos and sin to exp and as before expand rewrite  and simplify again as:

```
(sin(x)**2*cos(x)).rewrite(sin, exp).rewrite(cos, exp).expand().rewrite(exp, sin).simplify()
```

that returns:

```
cos(x)/4 - cos(3*x)/4
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Cannot run with a fresh installed Sympy, a possible bug in the latest release.

Comment: I made a small typo now is corrected you can check it again

Comment: I am using the last release too

Answer (score 2):

Here is a silly way to get this job done.

`trigsimp((sin(x)**2).rewrite(tan))`

returns:
`-cos(2*x)/2 + 1/2`

also works for

`trigsimp((sin(x)**3).rewrite(tan))`

returns
`3*sin(x)/4 - sin(3*x)/4`

but not works for

`trigsimp((sin(x)**2*cos(x)).rewrite(tan))`

retruns
`4*(-tan(x/2)**2 + 1)*cos(x/2)**6*tan(x/2)**2`